# How to group certain apps and add as a stack to the Dock?

Tags: applications, dock, shortcut

There is a set of apps I use for my job.
Instead of having them individually on the dock, I'd like to have them in a "stack" all together.

How can I create a stack on the dock and add these apps to it?

Comment: Finder > Help > Search... type Stacks and select "What are stacks?" where it says "You can add more stacks by dragging folders to the Dock. You can create as many stacks as you like. Stacks are located near the right end of the Dock."

Comment: And what about the part of putting apps in there?

Comment: What about it? It's common sense!  Also look at: [Mac Basics: Stacks are your shortcut in the Dock](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201955)

Comment: It's part of a question requiring an answer. "It's common sense!" IS not an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a folder in your user directory.  Make an alias for each app and move the alias to the folder.  Then drag the folder down to the dock, to the right of the divider line but left of the trash.

Once the folder is in the dock, click on it and the available apps will pop out and you can select whichever one you like.

P.S. this works for any kind of file or document, not just apps.  I.e., if there are favorite docs frequently used, you can put aliases in a folder and add the folder to the dock.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please expanding on alias and I will choose the answer as complete and correct.

Comment: Sure.  To make an alias of any file or app, select/highlight it, then choose "Make Alias" from the File menu (or use cmd-L). Doing so creates a new file called "App alias".  Drag this alias file to the folder as described above.

Comment: I read the Mac Basics article above, and noticed it does not mention aliases at all.  I have used Dock Stacks for years and have always found it easier to use aliases rather than the actual files. I.e., a folder in the dock may have aliases for files from several different folders.

Comment: @UncaMikey, Why bother with the alias? Why not simply create a subfolder in the Applications folder itself?

Comment: It's worth noting that this does not give you the same behaviour as you get with apps in the dock. If you start an app, it will still be inserted in the app part of the dock. It would be nice to have a way of grouping the apps in the app part.